# How to remove string before and after certain delimiter positions in R?

Tags: r, string

I have strings that look like this below

```
tt <- c("16S_M_T1_R1_S1_S50_R1_001.fastq.gz", "16S_M_T1_R1_S1_S50_R2_001.fastq.gz", 
"16S_M_T1_R1_S2_S62_R1_001.fastq.gz")
```

I want to delete everything before the 5th `_` and everything after the 6th `_`. 
The result I want is:
`S50, S50, S62`

I can do this in multiple steps by doing something like `sub("^(.*?_.*?_.*?_.*?_.*?_.*?)_.*", "\\1", tt)`, but I was wondering if there is a better one-step method to do this.

Comment: If it always follows pattern **S + digit + digit** you can use `sub(".*(S\\d{2}).*", "\\1", tt)`, assuming there are not other matches.

Comment: @gersh It can be single to multiple digits though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(tt, "_"), "[[", 6)
#[1] "S50" "S50" "S62"
```

Explanation: We use vectorised `strsplit` to split `tt` on every `"_"` resulting in a `list`; `sapply(..., "[[", 6)` then extracts the 6th element from every `list` element.

Alternatively you could use an explicit anonymous function

```
sapply(strsplit(tt, "_"), function(x) x[6])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` by placing an anchor for the start (`^`) followed by 5 instances of characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`) followed by a `_` and then capture the characters that are not a `_` (`([^_]+)`).  In the replacement, specify the second capture group (`\\2`)

```
sub("^([^_]+_){5}([^_]+).*", "\\2", tt)
#[1] "S50" "S50" "S62"
```